# Is there a way to get nodes where child node exists, without returning entire database?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Apologies if duplicated

I have a database set up in the following way:

```
- users
    - <random user id>
        - Projects
            - <random project id>
                - data
```

What I would like to do is: **get all users where the 'Projects' node exists and where <random project id> is equal to a specific value**, without getting the entire database and filtering the data inside my react-native application, because it seems wrong to just bring everything. I heard that it is possible to 'reverse engineer' react-native applications, and I fear that someone might listen the app requests and somehow get access to all that data, so I would like to bring only the data that belongs to a specific user.. if possible.

Today, I simply get all the data by using `firebase.database().ref('Users').on('value', ...);`
I could filter that data inside my app, but, as I said, I have security concerns..

But since I'm new to this, I could be looking at this with a wrong perspective, so I appreciate any help!

Thanks!

Comment: A Firebase query can have exactly one level of unknown keys and you have two. You cannot search across all users and all their projects. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I see.. perhaps I should restructure the way my database is setup. Thank you!